# Динамический импорт в JS и Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, импорт

Пишу веб-приложение с использованием фреймворка **Vue.js**. Возникла необходимость в использовании динамического импорта. Нужно импортировать компонент, используя параметр с его названием, а потом полученный компонент определить.

Синтакисис обычного динамического импорта в js следующий:

```
async () => {
    const module_path = 'module_path';
    const module = await import(module_path)
    module.default();
  }
```

Таким образом, использовать динамически импортированную библиотеку можно только внутри асинхронной функции. Мне же нужно использовать импортированный компонент в другом месте:

```
<template>
   <div>
      <!-- определение импортированного компонента -->
      <component v-bind:is="my_component"></component>
   </div>
</template>

<script lang="coffee">
   # Здесь нужно динамически импортировать компонент, чтобы потом определить его в строке 3.
   # Как сделать статический импорт - понятно (приведен ниже). Но мне нужен динамический.
   import my_component from "./component_title.Vue"
   
   export default {
      props: () -> {
         # Название компонента, который необходимо импортировать.
         # Передано из другого компонента.
         component_title: {type: String, default: null}
      }

      components: {
         # Объявляем компонент
         my_component: my_component
      }
   }
</script>
```

Можно ли реализовать динамический импорт в данной задаче?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

```
export default {
      components: {
         # Объявляем компонент
         'component_title': () => import('./component_title.Vue')
      }
   }
```